# ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier for a query involving inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have a very simple query that I am trying to execute:

```
select *
from submissions
  inner join (
    select *
    from hackers
      inner join challenges
        on hackers.hacker_id = challenges.hacker_id
  ) dtable
    on submissions.challenge_id = dtable.challenge_id
      and submissions.hacker_id = dtable.hacker_id;
```

Oracle rejects it with:

> ORA-00904: "DTABLE"."HACKER_ID": invalid identifier.

I have kept the alias `dtable` visible by keeping it outside the brackets.  Why is Oracle rejecting my query?

Comment: both the tables inside the `sub-select` is having `hacker_id` column. Try giving an alias name for one column

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT *` in your sub-query is a problem.

You have the same column name in both tables that are being joined.  This means that you're trying to create an inline-view called `dtable` where at least two columns have the same name *(in this case both tables have a `hacker_id` column and your use of `*` is essentially saying "use them both".)*.  You can't do that.

You're going to need `SELECT hackers.a, hackers.b, challenges.x, challenges.y, etc, etc` in your sub-query.  By being explicit in this way you can ensure that no two columns have the same name.

An alternative could be `SELECT hackers.*, challenges.a AS c_a, challenges.b AS c_b, etc`.

Either way you are being explicit about which fields to pick up, what their positions and names are, etc.  The end result being that you can then avoid columns having the same name as other columns.

Comment: Would it not be more accurate to say that he *can* construct such an inline view, but he cannot then reference columns of that view that are without unique names?

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're correct : http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=190f39e0fb5a7dc8990516207ca48676

Answer (score 1):

You do not need subqueries for this.  Your query is not actually "simple".  The simple form looks more like this:

```
select . . . 
from submissions s join
     hackers h
     on s.hacker_id = h.hacker_id join
     challenges c
     on s.challenge_id  = c.challenge_id;
```

Note that I removed the condition between `challenge` and `hackers` on `hacker_id`.  That extra `join` condition doesn't really make sense to me (although it might make sense if you provided sample data).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said: The sub-select selects two different columns `hacker_id` from two different tables. This confuses Oracle.

But there is no need for a sub-select

```
select * from
    submissions
    inner join challenges
        on submissions.challenge_id = challenges.challenge_id
    inner join hackers
        on submissions.hacker_id = hackers.hacker_id;
```